# How do I create a tree containing a dictionary of words?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Introduction: write a program to do text prediction suggestion (like Google does when you start typing a search term). That is, as the user
types, the program will show a list of N words that the user might be in the process of typing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2mq1.png)

Requirements: read in a file with words and build an internal representation

Part 1: The internal representation that you are to use is a tree with a branching factor of 26, one branch for each possible letter. Each node should also signify if ending in that node represents a word.

Example: For instance, given the string ”parrot”, following a path from the
**root** should end in a node that signifies that a word has occurred. Following a path for the string ”subantiq” should arrive at a node that signifies that a word does not end at that
node.

Confusion: I do not know how to create the tree in order to fill it with words from a list. Also, there is no constraint on the language.

My question are: 
1. Which language would be best for implementing this?
2. how do I create the tree that will read in a list of words, in the desired structure? Pseudo code in the best language?

Comment: Asking for language recommendations is EXPLICITLY off-topic as "opinions". And we are not here to do your homework for you, or tell you how to do it.

Comment: Use a language you are most experienced with. Add a tag for this language. Then, actually *try* to do it. If you're stuck, ask a specific question about that part.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Trie** data structure for this with a branching factor of 26.r

Now to answer your questions.

1. Which language would be best for implementing.
   ans: You can implement it either in python or in C++.

2.How do I create the tree that will read in a list of words in the desired structure.
ans: You can take reference from [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/).

Additionally you can take reference for pseudo code from [here.](http://dibaiee.ir/autocomplete-predict-trie)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start! I just want to clarify that my intent is to learn "how to think and, therefore, do" rather than have folks "do my homework" as Mark B put it. Anyway thanks! These are great resources!